# libopencm3 STM32G0B1RE usart_set_baudrate() results in getting stuck in blocking_handler()

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, usart, libopencm3

I am trying to setup USART on an STM32G0B1RE NUCLEO dev board using the libopencm3 library. I have looked at a variety of example code, but most is for the STM32**F** boards, which have different function names/signatures in libopencm3. I then adapted my code to use the STM32G0 signatures. Here is some representative example code, that seems to use the same functions as I am: https://rhye.org/post/stm32-with-opencm3-1-usart-and-printf/

When I call `usart_set_baudrate()`, I end up stuck in `blocking_handler()`, which is just an infinite loop. I expect it to set the baudrate and return, then have the rest of my code execute.

Is there some interrupt that defaults to `blocking_handler()` that I need to write my own handler for?

When using a USB-to-UART cable I do not see any output, whether I call `usart_set_baudrate()` or not. If I call `usart_set_baudrate()`, I of course won't see anything for the obvious reason that nothing is being sent because we are stuck in `blocking_handler()`. When I don't call `usart_set_baudrate()`, the `usart_send('A')` call goes through fine, but I don't see anything on GNU screen or minicom.

I tried defining `usart1_isr()`, but for the body I just wrote `return;` as I wasn't sure what to do. This did not help.

My code is the following:

- Send stream of 'A's on USART1
- Flash an LED

```c
#include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>
#include <libopencm3/stm32/usart.h>

#define RCC_LED1 RCC_GPIOA
#define PORT_LED1 GPIOA
#define PIN_LED1 GPIO5

void usart_setup(void);

int main(void) {
    rcc_clock_setup(&rcc_clock_config[RCC_CLOCK_CONFIG_HSI_16MHZ]);
    
    usart_setup();

    // Setup LED.
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_LED1);
    gpio_mode_setup(PORT_LED1, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, GPIO_PUPD_NONE, PIN_LED1);

    while (1) {
        usart_send(USART1, 'A');
        
        // Wait a bit.
        for (int i = 0; i < 800000; i++) {
            __asm__("nop");
        }
        // Flash LED.
        gpio_toggle(PORT_LED1, PIN_LED1);
    }
}

void usart_setup(void) {
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOC);
    rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART1);

    gpio_mode_setup(GPIOC, GPIO_MODE_AF, GPIO_PUPD_NONE, GPIO4 | GPIO5);
    gpio_set_af(GPIOC, GPIO_AF1, GPIO4 | GPIO5);

    usart_set_baudrate(USART1, 9600); // problem function
    usart_set_databits(USART1, 8);
    usart_set_stopbits(USART1, USART_STOPBITS_1);
    usart_set_mode(USART1, USART_MODE_TX);
    usart_set_parity(USART1, USART_PARITY_NONE);
    usart_set_flow_control(USART1, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

    usart_enable(USART1);
}
```

Comment: Get life, get a debugger in which you can single-step the problematic function; and don't use libraries you don't understand. If you insist on debugging this without debugger, delve into the function in question, read the code to know, what's exactly happening there, insert debugging outputs (e.g. blink a LED) at strategic points, observe disasm at around the problematic point, output content of registers at that point, etc. the usual stuff.